# Order Wordpress taxonomies differently for each post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I've a Wordpress theme with custom taxonomy and post type, I need the ability to set the order differently for each taxonomy in each post type.

For example I've "Hello World!" post that have this taxonomies "beginners, sentence, welcome message" And I've another post with the same taxonomies but I need this order "sentence, welcome message, beginners".
How can I make another order for each post?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can order terms like this:

```
$taxonomies = get_terms( 'taxonomy', array(
    'orderby'    => 'whateveryoulike',
    'hide_empty' => 0
 ));
```

see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

...or, if you need more complex comparison, sort it using `usort`

```
$taxonomies = usort( get_terms( 'taxonomy' ), function($a ,$b){
   //compare a/b
});
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: But I need to decide the order my self in each post, not to sort by something, custom order for each category in a post.

Comment: by what would that order be defined?

Comment: By me in the wp-admin, custom order for each post.